# Getting datetime from space seperated .dat file - python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a space separated .dat file using pandas and strip values to make a date. The data looks like this (three rows of data taken from the entire dataset for reference):

```
2.0140000e+003  1.0000000e+000  1.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000  2.7454583e+000  1.8333542e+002 -3.3580352e+001
2.0140000e+003  1.0000000e+000  2.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000 -6.1330625e+000  2.5187292e+002 -1.3752231e+001
2.0140000e+003  1.0000000e+000  3.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000 -3.0905729e+001  2.1295208e+002 -2.4507273e+001
```

The first six numbers make up the date (year, month, day, hour, minute, second).

I can import the data using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('daily.dat', sep='\s+', header=None)
```

and it is separated fine.

However, I would like to strip the first six entries of the row into a date. For example, from row one the first six numbers (or first six columns after importing to `df`) should make:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

Help?

Comment: you're probably looking for a solution with [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:

when you read a CSV/dat file without column names (header), you'll get a DF with numerical column names like as follows:

```
In [139]: df
Out[139]:
        0    1    2    3    4    5          6          7          8
0  2014.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.745458  183.33542 -33.580352
1  2014.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  -6.133063  251.87292 -13.752231
2  2014.0  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -30.905729  212.95208 -24.507273
```

columns:

```
In [140]: df.columns
Out[140]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')
```

[`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) can assemble datetime from multiple columns:

> Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys
>   can be common abbreviations like `[‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’, ‘minute’, ‘second’, ‘ms’, ‘us’, ‘ns’]`) or plurals of the same

```
In [141]: cols = ['year','month','day','hour','minute','second']

In [142]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, :6].rename(columns=lambda c: cols[c]))
```

dropping first 6 columns:

```
In [143]: df = df.iloc[:, 6:]

In [144]: df
Out[144]:
           6          7          8       date
0   2.745458  183.33542 -33.580352 2014-01-01
1  -6.133063  251.87292 -13.752231 2014-01-02
2 -30.905729  212.95208 -24.507273 2014-01-03
```

alternatively ([thanks @Idlehands for the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673059/getting-datetime-from-space-seperated-dat-file-python-pandas/48673325?noredirect=1#comment84345784_48673325)) we can drop it this way:

```
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[:6])
```

Comment: Great answer.  I was manually converting the `datetime` but this is much better.  One comment is the last drop might be a bit hard to read for some, I would have used `df.drop(columns=list(range(6)), inplace=True)` which is a more verbose.

Comment: @Idlehands, thank you for your comment - i've added it to the answer!

Comment: That works! But.. can you explain why you set 'cols'? Are these keys that are built into to_datetime? How come I cannot just send the columns I want to convert to datetime into to_datetime directly? Thanks!

Comment: @spencerchad, it's already in the answer - Pandas `pd.to_datetime()` expect specific column names - `The keys can be common abbreviations like [‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’, ‘minute’, ‘second’, ‘ms’, ‘us’, ‘ns’]) or plurals of the same`

Comment: Right. That is what I wanted to clarify as I did not fully understand, that pd.to_datetime() requires an actual name of a column and you cannot just use a reference to the position. Thank you.

Comment: @MaxU @Idlehands Adding `df.drop(columns=df.columns[:6], inplace=True)` results in this error for me.. `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-dfa197682a1b> in <module>()
      3 df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, :6].rename(columns=lambda c: cols[c]))
      4 
----> 5 df.drop(columns=df.columns[0], inplace=True)

TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'' `

Comment: @spencerchad, most probably you have an older Pandas version - i've tested it under Pandas 0.22.0

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('daily.dat', sep='\s+', header=None)

def to_datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second):
    return datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day),int(hour),int(minute),int(second))

df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda x: to_datetime(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]), axis=1).apply(str)

df.drop(list(range(6)),1,inplace=True)

print(df)

# output:
#           6          7          8             datetime
#0   2.745458  183.33542 -33.580352  2014-01-01 00:00:00
#1  -6.133063  251.87292 -13.752231  2014-01-02 00:00:00
#2 -30.905729  212.95208 -24.507273  2014-01-03 00:00:00
```